# Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить ошибки в скрипте

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день! Передо мной стоит следующая задача, с которой справиться самостоятельно не удается. При загрузке страницы спустя определенное время появляется всплывающее окно. В окне необходимо установить таймер с текстом "Закрыть окно можно будет через N секунд", по истечение которого должна появиться ссылка на закрытие окна. С этим и возникают трудности. Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить ошибки в скрипте. Благодарю за помощь!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var delay = 2;
  $('.pop_up').delay(delay * 1000).fadeIn(800);

  $(window).resize(function() {
    $('.pop_up').css({
      position: 'absolute',
      left: ($(window).width() - $('.pop_up').outerWidth()) / 2,
      top: ($(window).height() -
        $('.pop_up').outerHeight()) / 2
    });
  });
  $(window).resize();

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.close').fadeOut('fast')
  }, 10000);

  function timery() {
    var obj = document.getElementById('timer');
    obj.innerHTML--;
    if (obj.innerHTML == 0) {
      setTimeout(function() {}, 1000);
    } else {
      setTimeout(timery, 1000);
    }
  }
  setTimeout(timery, 1000);

});
```

```css
.pop_up {
  display: none;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.close {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pop_up">Я модальное окно
  <div id="timer">
    <div class="close">Закрыть окно</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать для этого setInterval():

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.timer').prepend('<div class="left">Можно будет закрыть через <span></span> секунд</div>'); // добавляем элемент для вывода секунд
  var delay = 2,
    seconds = 10; // кол-во секунда до появления кнопки
  $('.left span').text(seconds); // выводим изначальное кол-во секунд
  $('.pop_up').delay(delay * 1000).fadeIn(800, function() {
    var int;
    int = setInterval(function() { // запускаем интервал
      if (seconds > 1) {
        $('.left span').text(seconds - 1); // выводим оставшееся кол-во секунд
        seconds--; // уменьшаем кол-во секунд на 1
      } else {
        $('.left').remove(); // удаляем созданный элемент
        $('.pop_up .close').show(); // отображаем кнопку закрытия
        clearInterval(int); // очищаем интервал, чтобы он не продолжал работу "вхолостую"
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```css
.pop_up {
  display: none;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.close {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pop_up">Я модальное окно
  <div class="timer">
    <div class="close">Закрыть окно</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var delay = 2;
  $('.pop_up').delay(delay * 1000).fadeIn(800, function() {
    var timer1 = setInterval(function() {

      var lbl = $('#secsBeforeClose');
      var secondsLeft = +lbl.text() - 1;
      lbl.text(secondsLeft);

      if (secondsLeft == 0) {
        $('#closeAfterDiv').fadeOut('fast')
        $('.close').fadeIn('fast')
        clearInterval(timer1);
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```css
.pop_up {
  display: none;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.close {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pop_up">Я модальное окно
  <div id="timer">
    <div id="closeAfterDiv">
      Close after <label id="secsBeforeClose">10</label> seconds
    </div>
    <div class="close">Закрыть окно</div>
  </div>
</div>
```